# 'e' character doesn't show up in bash/cygwin until I type another character

Tags: bash, cygwin

As the title states, whenever I type the letter 'e' in my bash/cygwin shell, it doesn't show up until a type another character.

As an example, while typing "echo" I see nothing until I've typed the c, at which point both the e and c show up.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you taken a good look at your `stty -a` output?

Comment: $ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 64; columns 120; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = ^Z; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -tostop echoctl echoke

Comment: Presumably you were expecting that there might be something along the lines of foo=e?

Comment: Also examine `bind -p`.

Comment: I was wondering whether there was anything there, yes, though I was not sure which setting (if any) could achieve the effect you're seeing.  You're on Cygwin; that alters things, but it was worth a look.  AFAICS, there's nothing odd about the `stty -a` output, so that easy option isn't helpful.  Have you tried such obvious things as starting a new Cygwin shell and/or rebooting the machine?

Comment: @choroba - what am I look for in bind?  It does appear that "e" is mapped to self-insert and nothing else.

Comment: This is unlikely, but if you type e followed by a single quote ('), do you an accented e (é) instead of the two typed characters? It sounds as though "e" were behaving like a dead key.

Comment: @chepner e followed by a single quote just gives me e'

Comment: `It does appear that "e" is mapped to self-insert ...` That sounds like it is the cause of your problem. Unfortuantely, I don't know how to fix it, except find where it is set and remove it. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter Every single letter is mapped to self-insert - I'm assuming that means when you type said letter, it inserts itself.  I'm not having any trouble with other letters, so I wouldn't think that is the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly there is a `bind` macro defined; you can check this via `bind -s`.

Comment: >bind -s
"e[Z": "e--t"

I suspect that is the problem.  Any help in interpreting what this means/where it is getting set/how to unset it?

Comment: Possibly it's just a typo in your .bashrc or in ~/.inputrc; `bind -r "e[Z"` should unset it.

Comment: `bind -r "e[Z"` does seem to unset it, but does not seem to fix the issue - my e's are still not showing up until I type a second character.

Comment: After that, are there no more bindings beginning with `"e` shown by `bind -p` and `bind -s`?

Comment: `"e[Z": "e--t"` was the only binding I got when doing `bind -s`.  When doing `bind -p` the only other binding I see that starts with e is `"e: self-insert"`

Comment: Update: the "e[Z" was the issue.  I finally found where it was being set and commented it out, and things worked after restarting my shell.  Presumably the `bind -r` didn't work earlier because it needed a shell reset, and the reset was rebinding as well.